# Playing video with youtube-ios-player-helper

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have been trying to have my app stream videos from YouTube, learning from the AppCoda tutorial and so far I have successfully connected to its JSON database, and downloaded the info from the video I need. However, when I feed it to the YouTube player library, it gives me an error:

> `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."`

I checked against the AppCoda example and it seems that my app is working very similarly. I am even printing the videoID before calling the function to make sure that it is correct.

```
func getVideos(pID: String, completion: (result:String)->()) {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, videosURL).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    var videoID: [String] = []
                    for var i=0; i<json["items"].count; i++ {
                        let newID = json["items"][i]["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"].stringValue
                        videoID.append(newID)
                        defaults.setObject(videoID, forKey: "\(pID)videoID")
                    }
                    completion(result: "done")
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion(result: "done")
            }
        }
    }

        print(videoID) //Returns: 7zAxweqsSfo
        playerView.loadWithVideoId(videoID)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of the YouTube iOS Helper Library does not include the `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` file needed by the player.  See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/160) for related discussion.

The solution is to manually add the `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` to your project, or point Cocoapods at the master branch:

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git=>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your help!